# jQuery sortable sets incorrect initial offset if parent is scrollable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following problem with jquery sortable:

I have a container of elements with `overflow-x: scroll`. It contains sortable items (`display: block`) and (width > containers width).

If the container is scrolled to the left edge, there is no problem in sorting.

But if it is scrolled to the right, then when I start dragging, the sortable element jumps to the right. And as a result the element is far to the right.. but mouse is far to the left of the element while dragging..

It looks like jqueryui fails to get the initial offset of the element correctly because the parent is scrolled.

But the interesting part is that this happens only on the initial drag.. When I try to drag the second time, it is positioned correctly. And again.. when I reload the page it sets wrong position on first drag.. Also when the `change` event is fired, the elements jump back to the appropriate correct position.. So the issue can fix itself during the first drag too.

I've made a video to describe the problem: http://youtu.be/h1mBLAmYtgk

```
var conf = {
    helper: function (e, ui) {
        var helper_scope;
        helper_scope = ui.scope();
        helper_scope.$apply(function () {
            helper_scope.project.open = false;
        });
        return ui;
    },
    opacity: 0.4,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true
};
elm.sortable(conf);
```